# HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web.xml, http-status-code-405

I try to send some data but it seems like the Controller could not be clear found or could not handle the request.

test.jsp

```
<%@ page errorPage="exception.jsp"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page session="true" import="java.io.*,java.util.*"%>
<%@ page import="eng.ku.sku.exceed_vote.knt.*"%>


  <form name="AddForm" action="addtext" method="POST">
     <input type="hidden" name="todo" value="add">

Add text:<input type="text" name="text" />

    <input type="submit" value="Add">
  </form>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee                        

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
<servlet>
<servlet-name>exceed</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>eng.ku.sku.exceed_vote.knt.Controller</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>exceed</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/addtext</url-pattern>
```

Controller.java

```
package eng.ku.sku.exceed_vote.knt;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@WebServlet("/addtext")
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         throws ServletException, IOException {
      doPost(request, response);  // Same as doPost()
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
         HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

      // Retrieve the current session, or create a new session if no session exists.
      HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
      System.out.println("HIIEER");
      // Retrieve the shopping cart of the current session.


      // For dispatching the next Page
      String nextPage = "";
      String todo = request.getParameter("todo");

     // Dispatch to checkout.jsp
     nextPage = "/checkout.jsp";

     response.sendRedirect(nextPage);
     return;
   }
}
```

I read a lot of other topics but didnt find a solution. I hope u can help me :)

Comment: You seem to be not running the code you think you're running. Try to rebuild/redeploy/restart. By the way, why the duplicate servlet registration by web.xml and @WebServlet? Use the one or the other after having aligned your wrong web.xml version.

Comment: what is the error ? can you add the stacktrace ?

Comment: @Chris: it's in the title already. It's exactly the one which you'd get in webbrowser when servlet's `doPost()` is not been implemented or it incorrectly calls `super.doPost(req, res)` somewhere down in the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it was a wrong config of Tomcat.

It didn't sync the project changes.